# Shell script to trim characters after a particular length from 1st word of every line

Tags: shell, awk

I am writing a shell script to do the following task.
I have a file like this:

```
abcdfgfehg   124353552455
ldnaslbbdaj    134314314344
sdsdbbdbu    134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwdnowqdn  134134141232
```

I want the output file to be

```
abcdfgfeh 124353552455
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```

That is, all the names (1st word in every line) should be reduced to 9 characters and remaining characters trimmed. A space after that. and then the value of the name.

I know that the awk command prints the 1st word of evry line.

```
awk '{print $1}' ./input.txt
```

But how to trim the characters from the file so that each word is of length 9 and its value start after a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple printf would do -

```
awk '{printf ("%-10.9s%s\n", $1,$2)}' file
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{printf ("%-10.9s%s\n", $1,$2)}' file
abcdfgfeh 124353552455 
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```

**Test 2:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
abcdfgfehg   1243535ABCD55
ldnaslbbdaj    134314314344
sdsdbbdbu    134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwdnowqdn  134134141232

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{printf ("%-10.9s%s\n", $1,$2)}' file
abcdfgfeh 1243535ABCD55
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But if I have a value like ABCD instead of 12324 then it prints 0. How to rectify that?

Comment: No worries, just use `%s` instead of `%d` (I have updated the answer) and it would handle if the second column has `ABCD` instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the substring.

```
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ cat sample.txt
abcdfgfehg   124353552455
ldnaslbbdaj    134314314344
sdsdbbdbu    134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwdnowqdn  134134141232

[srikanth@myhost ~]$ awk '{ printf("%-.9s %s\n", $1, $2); }' sample.txt 
abcdfgfeh 124353552455
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo 141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```

Please take a look @Jaypal's answer. You can handle width and precision with printf.

Comment: You can handle indentation with `printf` using `width` and `precision`.

Comment: @JaypalSingh: Yes, seen your answer and then figured out. I thought that if I change my answer again, It's like copying your answer. So, I left it as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
> awk '{print substr($1,1,9),$2}' temp
abcdfgfeh 124353552455
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo 141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\S /&         /g;s/\(.\{9\}\)\S*\s*/\1 /' file
abcdfgfeh 124353552455
ldnaslbbd 134314314344
sdsdbbdbu 134134134314
auosdbo   141413434444
ihjidiqwd 134134141232
```